# Cable modem + 300 ft of Coax?

Tags: networking, cable, internet-speed, cable-modem, coaxial

I'm trying to get cable internet to a house in the woods. However, my ISP's connection is about 300 ft away. I want to run a coaxial cable from there to the house, but due to budget constraints, I can't afford more than RG6. Would that work out? My internet plan is 300 Mbps which is a lot more than I need, so I can accept if I won't get that.

**So my question is: if I connect my cable modem to my ISP with 300 ft of RG6 coax, will it a) connect to the internet, and b) do so at usable speeds (~30 Mbps?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand if you can't afford 300 Ft of RG6 cable how are you going achieve your goal? The maximum distance of RG6 is around 1,000 ft.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound, I *can* afford 300ft of RG6, was that not clear? I just want to make sure that it'll work.

Comment: See the second half of my comment.  No; You mention the connection is 300 ft away, then you mention you can't afford additional cable, never specify how much cable you currently have.  300 ft honestly isn't that large run considering most homes are 1,200 sqft  and likely have multiple runs of that length to multiple segments of the home.  *Your biggest problem is if the cable is graded to be ran out doors.*

Comment: Your cable company may be willing to provide you with direct bury coax in 0.500 inch diameter (or greater) depending on their scrap pile. Fittings at each end will connect to the house and service tap. If it's not underground, the aerial portion may get trickier. If you can afford it, bury the largest diameter PVC you can afford to make future management easier. Use sweeps at the ends, not elbows.

Comment: Get the cable for direct burial . Our ISP uses RG6 and buries it for distribution to houses.

Comment: However you wire it. **be sure to include lightning protection at both ends of the cable.** You might consider just WiFi, using inexpensive directional antennas, such canttennas: https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cantenna , https://jacobsalmela.com/2013/09/07/wi-fi-cantenna-2-4ghz-how-to-make-a-long-range-wi-fi-antenna/

Comment: As an update, I decided to risk it and I bought 250 ft (which was *just* enough) of quad-shielded coax from ebay. I set it up and it works fine, so I guess this is doable at least occasionally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOCSIS, the protocol/technology that cable modems use, can use frequencies up to about 1GHz. Without knowing exactly how your DOCSIS ISP has allocated the frequencies on the system in your neighborhood, it's best to engineer your cable run to make sure it has good signal characteristics all the way from the lowest frequencies up to at least 1GHz.

RG6 can lose up to about 6.1dB per 100ft at 1GHz. Your 18.3dB of loss over a 300ft run is an awful lot to make up for, but it's doable.

The ideal DOCSIS signal level is 0dBmV, ±7. Some people consider ±10 to be acceptable. So your signal from your ISP, at the original connection point, would need to be coming in hot at +10dBmV, so that after your 300ft of RG6 takes away 18.3dB, you'd still be above -10dBmV at your new location for your cable modem.

RG6 loses a lot less at lower frequencies. This difference in attenuation across the relevant frequencies is known as "cable tilt". There are filters you can buy to level out the cable tilt, so that the loss ends up more uniform across all frequencies. These are needed so that you can keep both the low frequencies and the high frequencies within the acceptable signal level range.

So, overall, if you do your homework, you can likely make this work, but you might need to buy your own cable tilt filters and DOCSIS-savvy bidirectional amplifier. Note that just any coax cable TV amp won't do; those usually amplify the downstream frequencies only. For DOCSIS to work, you'll likely need something that can amplify the "upstream" frequencies (usually 5-42MHz) in the upstream direction, and separately amplify the downstream frequencies (usually 52-1002MHz) in the downstream direction.

Alternatively, if your DOCSIS ISP (Cable TV provider) has a helpful lineman/technician or engineer, it's *possible* they can tweak their amps/filters that serve your house to make up for your extra 300ft run. I wouldn't count on cooperation from them, though.

One helpful thing you could do is hook up your DOCSIS modem at the original location, log into its admin pages and look at the DOCSIS signal levels across the various channels, including DOCSIS 3.1 OFDM channels. This will let you see what signal levels you're seeing as-is, so you know which way it will need to be adjusted.

If you can't get the signal levels in-spec across the whole frequency range, all bets are off. If they're too far out of spec, it might not work at all. But if you CAN get the signal levels in-spec, you should be able to get full speed, even DOCSIS 3.1 gigabit+ downstream speeds, if your ISP supports that and you subscribe to that level of service plan.

Comment: It's a good idea; however, if I was able to get power to to the ISP's connection I would've just put the modem there and gotten a 300 ft ethernet cord for a similar price.

Comment: I was actually about to suggest that -- a long ethernet run really is the way to go. And 300ft is about the about the maximum cable run ethernet can support, so you should be golden. You can even power the cable modem via PoE (== power-over-Ethernet), avoiding the need for mains power at the connection point.

Answer (score 0):

RG6 is rated for runs up to 1000 feet, so 300 feet should not be an issue. I checked some various charts and they don't show a performance drop until significantly longer runs are made. Make sure you use outdoor rated cable.

Comment: "RG6 is rated for runs up to 1000 feet" is meaningless without context of exactly what kind of signaling protocol the rating scheme was intended for.